# Django and real time updates from the server on a REST resource

Tags: javascript, django, websocket, django-rest-framework

Context: I am using django (1.10) + django-restframework. I am implementing an application that will need real time updates from the server.

I would like, from the frontend, to be able to receive live updates being performed on the database. I know that the solution is to use websockets. However, I'd like to avoid having to manage low-level websocket business. I was wondering if there is a high level solution that would integrate nicely with django and django-restframework and if not, it that would require a lot of work to do and where I should start.

As a user, what I'd like to do would on the backend is to:

```
# define a model
class MyModel(models.Model):
  myField = models.CharField(max_length=128)

# define a serializer
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = MyModel
      fields = (
        'myField',
    )

# define a class based view (a la django-restframework)
class MyModelList(ListCreateAPIView):
  queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
  serializer_class = MyModelSerializer

# define a path to this resource
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^/api/my-models$', MyModelList.as_view(), name='my-model-list'),
]
```

This defines a resource on the server. Then on the frontend I would like to:

```
// create a real-time resource
myModelResource = $rt_resource('/api/my-models');

myModelResource.fetch(function (myModels) {
  // Retrieve all the myModels from the list
});
myModel.watch(function (myModels) {
  // Called when the table myModel is changed. The entire list is returned
});
```

This API is inspired by [Horizon](https://horizon.io/).

My first question is: is there something similar? There is something called django-channels, but it seems overly complicated, not really integrating with django-restframework and it does not exatly do what I want.

If, as I suspect, there is no proper answer to my first question. My second question would be the following: In order to retrieve real time feed, I need to connect to the post-save signal of my model. So I need to retrieve the model from the url. But the url in django links to a 'view':

```
url(r'^/api/my-models$', MyModelList.as_view(), name='my-model-list'),
```

I don't see how to retrieve the underlying model to then hook to the post-save message.

Comment: Hm, I'm surprised this post isn't more popular. I'm in the same boat as you, Luke. Did you settle on a solution?

Comment: Well, for the particular instance of my problem, none of the presented solutions matched my simple needs. So I started writing [my own solution](https://github.com/jdmichaud/rtr) and realize that it was just too complicated. So I simplified it even further by taking django out of the equation with a simple [key-value store backend with a long polling facility](https://github.com/jdmichaud/skvs). But again, these are solution to my specific needs...

Answer (score 0):

I would disagree with you on your conclusion to Django Channels, but if you don't like it and prefer different solution that has some frontend support (and integrates with the DRF), have a look at [Snorky](http://snorky.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Indeed Snorky seems very intersting, especially as it seems to work well with DRF **and** angular. I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your use case, but you have several solutions:

#### Web socket with Django Channels

Still in beta, I only recommend it if you know what you do with it and you really need it.
For only one push, it might be unnecessary.

#### External push service

Such as [Pusher](https://pusher.com/) you can install it easily both on backend and frontend and it allows you to send pushes without a lot of pain. But it's not free.

#### HTTP polling

If you have an API, the simpler way to retrieve an information from the server is to contact the API frequently until the information is available. It is the more reliable solution.

You can do it with a simple `fetch` in a `setInterval`. Even, you can use a [battery friendly setInterval](https://github.com/marmelab/battery-friendly-timer) (if the push is not critical)

Comment: External Push Service: my application will be used out of a connection. And I don't want to depend on a external service. HTTP polling: Yes, that's one of the option for the way to communicate with the backend.